# Scaling <img> located in a <div> with 'overflow: hidden'

Tags: html, css, firefox

Today I updated Firefox to version 45 (current). After that I started to have problems with scaling thumbnails located in div with overflow: hidden. On mouseover the thumbnail for a millisecond scaling down and after this doing correct action . When you hover mouse the thumbnail second time, everything is working properly. The problem returns after clearing the browser cache or a long time without mouse over the thumbnail. The funny thing is that on other browsers working properly(Chrome, Opera).

[CSS]

```
.galleryimg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .15 linear;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow:
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.thumbnail {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

[HTML]

```
<div class="galleryimg">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://theactivephotographer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TAP_Ad_300x300.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x084g6fu/)

Comment: I suggest you add `firefox` tag

Comment: I just checked in my mozilla, its working..

Comment: Works fine in my firefox version 45.0